# Does using bs() to fit splines work with as.factor with geeglm?

Tags: splines, geepack

I am running analyses of longitudinal health data. Each subject has two health measurements—one at age 60, and one at age 80. Subjects are marked as either "healthy" or "sick" at each measurement. Subjects are divided into birth cohorts, based on their birth year (e.g., 1920, 1921,1922, etc.).

I want to analyze the influence of a subject's birth year (Birth_Year) on their health status (Health_Status). Since a given subject's health measurements are not independent of each other, I have been using geeglm (from geepack) to fit the data. What I have done so far is compare the QICC of a linear model, in which subjects are not stratified with respect to age (Age), with the QICC of a stratified linear model, in which they are. The models look like this:

Non-Stratified Model:

`non_stratified_model <- geeglm(Health_Status ~ 1 + Birth_Year, family=binomial, data=health_data, id=Subject_ID, corstr="exchangeable")`

Stratified Model:

`stratified_model <- geeglm(Health_Status ~ as.factor(Age) - 1 + Birth_Year:as.factor(Age), family=binomial, data=health_data, id=Subject_ID, corstr="exchangeable")`

What I would now like to do is fit a spline to these data. This is not a problem when dealing with the non-stratified model:

Non-Stratified Model w/ Spline Fit:

`non_stratified_model_spline_fit <- geeglm(Health_Status ~ bs(1 + Birth_Year, knots=mean(Birth_Year), family=binomial, data=health_data, id=Subject_ID, corstr="exchangeable")`

However, when I try to fit a spline to the stratified data, I get a number of error messages.

Stratified Model w/ Spline Fit:

`stratified_model_spline_fit <- geeglm(Health_Status ~ bs(as.factor(Age) - 1 + Birth_Year:as.factor(Age)), family=binomial, data=health_data, id=Subject_ID, corstr="exchangeable")`

These are the error messages:

```
  length of 'derivs' is larger than length of 'x'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(as.factor(Age), 1) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Cohort_Year:as.factor(Age) :
  numerical expression has 2062 elements: only the first used
3: In Cohort_Year:as.factor(Age) :
  numerical expression has 2062 elements: only the first used
4: In as.factor(Age) - 1 + Cohort_Year:as.factor(Age) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I don't need help working through these error messages. My general question is whether anyone is familiar with how to fit splines to stratified data when the underlying model is a geeglm object. Alternatively, should I be using a function other than geeglm to perform this task? I am not necessarily wedded to geeglm, but whatever function I use would need to take into account the fact that my data are correlated within subjects.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You have an expression inside the spline function `bs(as.factor(Age) - 1 + Birth_Year:as.factor(Age))` instead of a (numeric) variable. There are only two distinct values for Age in the data, so spline(Age) doesn't make sense. Do you intend two splines for Birth_Year, one for each Age?

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov for the response. Yes, two splines for Birth_Year, one for each age.

Comment: Have you tried `bs(Birth_Year)*as.factor(Age)`? That should at least get around the non-numeric argument to `bs()`.

Comment: This might work out numerically but I really think this two different splines for Age is a meaningful idea. The birth year of a person is the the same whether the visit is at Age = 60 or Age = 80. You have one person with two measurements, something like baseline at T0 = 60 followup at T1 = 80. Wouldn't `Health_at_80 ~ s(Birth_Year) + Health_at_60` make more sense?

Comment: @EdM, thank you for the tip! That seems to do the trick.